# War file failed to deploy it on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7, grails-2.0

I am using Grails Frame work and when i create a war file and deploy it on Tomcat-7, I am getting the below error. But some time the deployment is success.

Jul 29, 2016 10:19:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 29, 2016 10:19:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016-07-29 10:19:23,951 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  lifecycle.ShutdownOperations  - Error occurred running shutdown operation: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Jul 29, 2016 10:19:23 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jul 29, 2016 10:19:23 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 29, 2016 10:19:23 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@6b0bbde6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Can anybody tell me what is the problem here ? I believe this error is coming because its not able to connect to mysql database due to some problem.

Comment: You must have deployed your war without restarting the tomcat and it was not able to stop all the threads it has created previously. Try restarting the tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the response Prakash. I restarted the tomcat couple of times but getting the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

If you Google for this phrase: `SEVERE: Error listener` You'll get some explanation why this is happening.

Tomcat doesn't display by default log/exception messages in `Listeners and Filters` initialization code.

Try adding a `logging.properties` file and place it to WEB-INF/classes in your `war` with the following content:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to make it easier you can do it automatically in `BuildConfig.groovy` in the following way:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
      def tomcatLoggingProperties = '''org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler'''
    new File("${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties").write tomcatLoggingProperties
}
```

After deploying the war to Tomcat inspect your `catalina.out` log file. It should now give more feedback about the problem.